# UWP C# Saving DeviceInformation to ApplicationData

Tags: c#, uwp, settings, windows-iot-core-10, application-data

I am trying to save `device information` in my application.
I managed to save `as string` to `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings` but unable to save as `deviceinformation` which I need to use to enumerate my device when the app starts.

I am not sure what is the right approach to do so.
Can somebody advise?
Thanks.

```
    const string MicDeviceNameKey = "MicDeviceName";
    const string MicDeviceIDKey = "MicDeviceID";
    IPropertySet settings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values;

    public string MicDeviceName
    {
        get
        {
            object setting;
            if (settings.TryGetValue(MicDeviceNameKey, out setting))
                return (string)setting;
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            settings[MicDeviceNameKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public DeviceInformation MicDeviceID
    {
        get
        {
            if (settings[MicDeviceIDKey] != null)
                return (DeviceInformation)settings[MicDeviceIDKey];
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            settings[MicDeviceIDKey] = value;
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Updated**

I am using `AudioGraph` to route mic input to line output.
Is there anyway to work around  where I can load saved `Device Information` for `Capture` and `Render` device to initialize `AudioGraphSettings`.

```
public async Task CreateMicRoute(DeviceInformation output, DeviceInformation input)
    {
        // ################################################################################################
        // Register the Output Source for the Playback
        var settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
        settings.QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.LowestLatency;
        settings.PrimaryRenderDevice = output;

        var result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

        if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create graph
            //rootPage.NotifyUser(String.Format("AudioGraph Creation Error because {0}", result.Status.ToString()), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }

        //Create Audio Graph
        micAudioGraph = result.Graph;

        // ################################################################################################
        // Create a device input node
        var inProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Medium);
        var DeviceInputResult = await micAudioGraph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Media, inProfile.Audio, input);
        if (DeviceInputResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create device input node
            return;
        }

        // Set the Created Audio Input Node to Device Input Node
        deviceInputNode = DeviceInputResult.DeviceInputNode;

        // Create a device output node
        var DeviceOutputResult = await micAudioGraph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        if (DeviceOutputResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            // Cannot create device output node
            return ;
        }
        // Selected Output device from Audio Graph is set to Device Output Node
        deviceOutputNode = DeviceOutputResult.DeviceOutputNode;

        // ################################################################################################           
        if (micAudioGraph == null)
            return;
    }
```

Comment: Is deviceinformation  string type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?view=winrt-19041#remarks),

> For both `LocalSettings` and `RoamingSettings`, the name of each setting can be 255 characters in length at most. Each setting can be up to 8K bytes in size and each composite setting can be up to 64K bytes in size.

The [**Windows Runtime data types are supported**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrt/base-data-types) for app settings. But `DeviceInformation` is not in the support list. For your scenario, we suggest your save some key value about  `DeviceInformation` such device id device kind. and get the device with device id.

**Update**

`DeviceInformation` contains [`CreateFromIdAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.createfromidasync?view=winrt-19041) method, you could store the DeviceInformation's id in to local setting, and retrieve `DeviceInformation` with the following code.

```
DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync("Device ID");
```

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT thanks. However, I am using `AudioGraph` where i need to parse `Device Information` to both `AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media)` & `CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync` . Is there any work around ?

Comment: I have update the answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank @NicoZhu-MSFT